# How to programmatically take a picture from epson scanner?

Tags: python, windows, delphi, scanning, epson

How to programmatically get a picture from epson scanner (Epson Perfection V19) on Windows.
Any examples please.
Python is better or ... any development environment (Delphi, C#, C++).

Thanks!

Comment: retrieving scanned picture from most image scanners is usually done through Twain interface. So best choice for you is to go and look form a Twain library for your preferred programming language and then work from there.

Comment: there is another interface called SANE, and it seems quite common. There are python libs too

Answer (score 2):

Done! Through Twain interface

Python 3.8.2

Install the twain module from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twainmodule](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twainmodule)

Python code:

```
import twain

sm = twain.SourceManager(0)
ss = sm.OpenSource("Epson Perfection V19")

ss.RequestAcquire(0,0)
rv = ss.XferImageNatively()
if rv:
    (handle, count) = rv
    twain.DIBToBMFile(handle, 'scan_01.bmp')
```